# PyEphem - calculate the next ISS transit on a full moon

Tags: astronomy, pyephem

How can I use PyEphem to calculate the next transit of ISS in front of the full moon? I'm absolutely clueless about that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Clues: http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/tutorial.html#loading-bodies-from-catalogues where it says "There is one other database format with which PyEphem is familiar: the NORAD Two-Line Element format (TLE) used for earth satellites", and http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/realdata/sightings/SSapplications/Post/JavaSSOP/orbit/ISS/SVPOST.html which has the latest TLEs.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question, but I wrote https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/ASTRO/bc-solve-overflow-33944589.c to solve this and came up with... a surprise.

Because the ISS is so close to the Earth, its position in the sky varies widely depending where on Earth you are.

Combined with its rapid orbital period of just 90 minutes, ISS is transiting the Moon virtually constantly somewhere in the world:

https://www.calsky.com/cs.cgi/Satellites/4

I realize you asked about the full moon specifically, but the transits occur virtually constantly daily, including on the dates of the next full moons.